# Capturing USB Storage Attached Intent on Android

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I've been trying to get the intent from when my USB storage device is attached and not having any luck. I've modified my manifest file to include both

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
    <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
                    android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
</intent-filter>
```

and

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED" />
    <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED"
                    android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
</intent-filter>
```

in the activity, with the appropriate VID/PID set in the device_filter.xml file. The activity itself has a broadcastreceiver

```
private static final BroadcastReceiver mUsbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED.equals(action)) {
                Log.i("MyActivity", "USB Attach Intent Captured");
            }
            if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED.equals(action)) {
                Log.i("MyActivity", "USB Detach Intent Captured");
            }
            if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED.equals(action)) {
                Log.i("MyActivity", "Stuff");
            }
        }
    };
```

I'm not seeing the BroadcastReceiver being called at all, so I don't think my issue is necessarily that I'm filtering for the wrong action. I just don't know what previous step I'm missing.

Comment: Hi! found any solution to this problem?

Comment: @NishanKhadka Hey Nishan, it's been a while since I've worked on this project and I no longer have access to the code I had written. Unfortunately I do not believe I had ended up finding a solution to this problem. We moved away from working with Android for our product.

Comment: Well, I think I found a work around using handlers hehe . Thanks for your reply.. :)

Comment: @NishanKhadka Awesome, glad to hear it. If you wouldn't mind posting your solution I'm sure it would help others and I'd gladly accept it!